# Send email with Nodemailer and Office365 mail.protection.outlook.com link (without Auth)

Tags: node.js, firebase, office365, nodemailer

can we send Emails using Nodemailer and Office365 without Auth?

> package.json

```
"nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
"nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
```

If we take a look on the Nodemailer source code (https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/lib/smtp-transport/index.js#L56) it should work

I am using Using {xxxxxxxxx}.mail.protection.outlook.com as my connector. It guy has connected connector with Firebase IP address.

I have already tried with:

```
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
        smtpTransport({
            host: 'xxxxxxxxxxx.mail.protection.outlook.com',
            port: 587,
            secureConnection: false,
            tls: {
                ciphers:'SSLv3',
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            },
        })
    );
```

But I am getting an error "530 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail" -> I am using Firebase.

Thx

Comment: For an instance, even If I ignore "How", why do you expect it to work without auth?

Comment: @LalitFauzdar because IT guy told me that if he add my public IP Address of server to the Office365 I can use only host name provided from him (xxx.mail.protection.outlook.com) to send email via SMPT. However, every example in the nodemailer Documentation is with an Auth object so that was the reason why I have posted this question. On the other side, if you look at the source code of Nodemailer, then Auth should be required If you cant send emails withouth Auth (but that is not the case)... or I am wrong with this statement